# ssdt - Schema Compare - ignore log files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, database-schema, sql-server-data-tools, schema-compare

I am running schema compares from the command line.

The ONE option that does NOT seem to have a toggle is log/sql files.

Regardless of my setting every single toggle to OFF I STILL get the sql/log files showing up in my compare results.

What do I do to toggle these darn things OFF?

Comment: I found if you toggle the schema some objects of the schema keeps untoggled. Everytime I must check all files to see if they are toggles or not, very unpratical and annoying